# About changing JavaScript associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arraylist

I have below array.

```
Array(
　　{ id : 1, name : 'aaaa' },
　　{ id : 2, name : 'bbbb' }
)
```

need change to below

```
Array(
　　id : Array( 1 ,2 ),
　　name : Array( 'aaaa' ,'bbbb' )
)
```

Comment: Arrays **in javascript** only have numerical indexes, not string keys.  What you are asking for is to reduce the array to an Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output is an object, not an array. You can use reduce to get it

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'aaaa'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbbb'
  }
];

const res = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  Object.entries(b).forEach(([k, v]) => a[k] = (a[k] || []).concat(v));
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```